# How do I redirect a page based on the selected value in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my UITableView I have (Google,Facebook,Yahoo), and based on the selection, it should be redirected to that page

What do I need to write in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Google is your friend... Search for "Segue"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"LoginUrl"]]];
}
```

**If your key is** `LoginUrl`

Comment: What ? couldn't get you.. Come again

Comment: can you please see this link?i have asked that question here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827179/how-to-redirect-page-when-click-uitableview-contained-data?noredirect=1#comment22516950_15827179

Comment: where you will get the url form the response Array.. all are blank rite ?

Comment: i don't have rights to show that URL to others,bcoz that was purchased from Azure

Comment: {"Name":"Windows Live™ ID","LoginUrl":"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2faccesscontrol.windows.net%2f&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fconverse.accesscontrol.windows.net%2fv2%2fwsfederation&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&wctx=cHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPXVybiUzYW9yaW4uY29udmVyc2U1","LogoutUrl":"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignout1.0","ImageUrl":"http://www.microsoft.com/favicon.ico","EmailAddressSuffixes":[]}, and so on......for remaining

Comment: that is what you are getting from JSON

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code : Place your selection code below Or through custom initialization pass the selected to single value to controller  and handle based on valu sent

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self moveToNewViewControllerForRow:(indexPath.row)];
    }

    -(void)moveToNewViewControllerForRow:(NSInteger)forTheRow{

        switch (forTheRow) {
            case 0:
            {
            }

                break;
            case 1 :
            {
            }
                break;
            case 2 :
            {
            }
                break;   
        }


    }
```